# Vim file completion from the project root with <C-x><C-f>

Tags: vim

```
.(.git repository)
├── css
│  └── style.css
└── index.html
```

I'm in `index.html`, and type `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/<C-x><C-f>`.

Expected completion: `css/`, `index.html`.

But now: `/Applications/`, `/bin/`, `/usr/`, etc.

Is there a good .vimrc settings or plugins to solve this?`

Comment: `/` is the root of your filesystem so Vim does the only thing it can be expected to do in this case: suggest completions from the root of your filesystem. Remove that leading slash and you will get the suggestions you want.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to complete the project directory with "/".

Currently, I move the cursor back to type “/“ after completion.